# iOS custom back button bad transition

Tags: ios, swift

I want to customize the image for a back button in just a viewController.
So for this viewController i have:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = #customImage
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = #restoreImage
}
```

But when im displaying the previous viewController (viewWillDissapear is called) this previous viewController wait until its displayed to set the image (if i swippe this doesnt happen):

[image]

Comment: set `navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage` in each viewController's `viewDidLoad:`

Comment: in viewWillAppear of the previous countroller set the indicator

Comment: This doesn’t work. In fact viewWillDisappear of current vc it’s called before that.

Comment: Is my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, changes of image (imageSize 40 * 40) working fine. You can try this.

SecondViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    var backButtonImage = UIImage(named: "lineBack.png")
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backButtonImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
}
```

ThirdViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    var backButtonImage = UIImage(named: "roundBack.png")
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backButtonImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
}
```